# CustomScrollView with SliverFillRemaining, always have bottom overflowed with last element

Tags: flutter

I am having hard time on scrolling. I created this Flutter application that we have 4 TextFields and they all overflow when keyboard shows up.

So I added **CustomScrollView** with **sliver** **SliverFillRemaining**  (First I implemented SingleChildScrollView It does not fit my needs.)

My Initial page looks like this which is ok

[image]

But When I open the keyboard

[image]

It overflows. So I thought that maybe button has some problem and for debugging I added 3 **Text** and now which looks like this.

[image]

Strangely Button now does not overflow but the TextFields overflow. Why these last elements overflow? I tried to wrapping button with **Expanded** and it worked but Now button has strange sizes when keyboard appears.

First Picture Keyboard Not Open with Expanded
Second Picture Keyboard Open with Expanded -> Sizes Are Different

[image]

[image]

How can i solve that? I am putting my all pages code here. I called this code from Scaffold. Also I am changing all the colors to the nonsense since they are not defined in your computer.

I am calling Checkout like that  **home: SafeArea(child: Scaffold(body: Checkout())),**

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class Checkout extends StatefulWidget {
  const Checkout({super.key});

  @override
  State<Checkout> createState() => _Checkout();
}

class _Checkout extends State<Checkout> {
  void payOrder() {
    print("Pay Order is clicked");
  }

  void swithcMyCards() {
    print("Switch To My Card Panel");
  }

  void switchNewCards() {
    print("Switch To New Card Panel");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverFillRemaining(
          hasScrollBody: false,
          child:  MainBody(), 
        )
      ],
        
    );
  }

  Widget MainBody() {
    return Column(
          children: [
            TitleRow(),
            CardButtons(
              switchMyCards: swithcMyCards,
              switchNewCards: switchNewCards,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
              width: double.infinity,
            ),
            CardInputSections(),
            Spacer(),
            Text("We will send you an order details to your"),
            Text("email after the succesfull payment"),
            
            Expanded(child: PayButton()),
           


          ],
        );
  }

  Widget PayButton() {
    return Container(
      height: 50,

      child: ElevatedButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Color.fromARGB(255, 42, 212, 73)),
            foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(const Color.fromARGB(255, 137, 95, 95)),
          ),
          onPressed: payOrder, 
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.lock),
              const SizedBox(width: 10,),
              Text("Pay for the order")
            ],
          )  
        ),
    );
  }
}

class CardInputSections extends StatelessWidget {
  const CardInputSections({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Text("Card Number", style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 108, 108, 108)
            ),),
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: TextField(
            obscureText: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              filled: true,
              fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 125, 125, 129),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)
              ),
              labelText: 'Enter Credit Card',
            ),
          ),
        ),

        SizedBox(height: 10,),
    
        Row(
          children: [
            Text("Cardholder Name", style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 54, 54, 54)
            ),),
          ],
        ),
    
        Container(
          child: TextField(
            obscureText: true,
           decoration: InputDecoration(
              filled: true,
              fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 180, 180, 190),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)
              ),
              labelText: 'Name',
            ),
          ),
        ),

        SizedBox(height: 10,),

        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text('Expiry Date', style: TextStyle(
                    color : const Color.fromARGB(255, 63, 63, 63),
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    )
                  ),
                   // Add some spacing between title and TextField
                  TextField(
                    // Your first TextField properties go here
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "MM / YYYY",
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 38, 38, 39),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)
                      ),),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 16.0), // Add some spacing between the columns
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text('CVV / CVC', style: TextStyle(
                    color : const Color.fromARGB(255, 65, 65, 65),
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    )
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    // Your second TextField properties go here
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "_ _ _ ",
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 53, 53, 54),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),



        SizedBox(height: 10,),

      ],
    );
  }
}

class TitleRow extends StatefulWidget {
  const TitleRow({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<TitleRow> createState() => _TitleRowState();
}

class _TitleRowState extends State<TitleRow> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Text(
              "Checkout",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 22,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 54, 54, 54)),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Icon(Icons.credit_card),
          ],
        ),
        Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              "₹ 1,527",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 89, 92, 90),
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            Text(
              "Including GST (18%)",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 46, 45, 45)),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CardButtons extends StatefulWidget {
  Function switchNewCards;
  Function switchMyCards;

  CardButtons(
      {super.key, required this.switchMyCards, required this.switchNewCards});

  @override
  State<CardButtons> createState() => _CardButtonsState();
}

class _CardButtonsState extends State<CardButtons> {
  final int NEW_CARDS_SELECTED = 0;
  final int MY_CARDS_SELECTED = 1;

  int cardChoice = 0;

  void handleNewCardTap() {
    setState(() {
      cardChoice = NEW_CARDS_SELECTED;
    });

    widget.switchNewCards();

    print("Handle New Card is clicked");
  }

  void handleMyCardsTaps() {
    setState(() {
      cardChoice = MY_CARDS_SELECTED;
    });

    widget.switchMyCards();
    print("My Card is clicked");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ElevatedButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                        cardChoice == NEW_CARDS_SELECTED
                            ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 133, 165, 139)
                            : const Color.fromARGB(255, 134, 134, 142)),
                    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                        RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ))),
                onPressed: () => handleNewCardTap(),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.credit_card,
                      color: cardChoice == NEW_CARDS_SELECTED
                          ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 165, 154, 154)
                          : const Color.fromARGB(255, 92, 86, 86),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "New Cards",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: cardChoice == NEW_CARDS_SELECTED
                              ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 120, 113, 113)
                              : const Color.fromARGB(255, 54, 54, 54)),
                    )
                  ],
                )),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ElevatedButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                        cardChoice == MY_CARDS_SELECTED
                            ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 149, 176, 154)
                            : const Color.fromARGB(255, 122, 122, 135)),
                    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                        RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ))),
                onPressed: () => handleMyCardsTaps(),
                child: Text(
                  "My Cards",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: cardChoice == MY_CARDS_SELECTED
                          ? Color.fromARGB(255, 31, 29, 29)
                          : const Color.fromARGB(255, 37, 37, 37)),
                )),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```